# Can I undo several cells back to zero with one click in Excel?

Tags: excel

Is there any way I can undo several cell values with one click? I would like to make one click and undo all cells back to zero.

Comment: Do you mean using VBA, or some other way?  We need more information to help.

Answer (score 1):

You can record a macro, and then assign it to a button.

To learn more about recording macros: http://www.wikihow.com/Write-a-Simple-Macro-in-Microsoft-Excel

To assign a macro to a button: http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Custom-Macro-Button-in-Excel